# Properties of stalks, only using the categorical definition

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

I am taking some time to reflect on the slogan "the universal property encapsulates all you need to know"; any reference or comment on this is very welcome.

Let $x$ be a point of a topological space $X$. Let $\mathcal F$ be a presheaf (or a sheaf if need be) on $X$.

Assuming that

- $\mathcal F$ takes values in a category where elements make sense
- the stalk $\mathcal F_x$ is by definition the colimit on the filtered/directed category indexed by open neighbourhoods $U$ of $x$,

can we easily infer from the universal property that

1. any element of $\mathcal F_x$ comes from one of the $\mathcal F(U)$
2. two "functions" have the same stalk at $x$ if and only if their restrictions to a common open set $U$ coincide

without knowing the usual construction?

I was only able to find on page 5 of Sheaf theory, Tennison that the converse is true (a cocone with those properties will be a universal cocone) in the category of sets..

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more to be seen as a hint: For a sheaf of sets the answer to your first question is particularly easy: assume there is a element in $f \in \mathcal{F}_x$ that doesnt come from some $\mathcal{F}(U)$ and now take $ \mathcal{F}_x \cup \{1\}$ where $1$ should be seen as an arbitrary element that wasn't already in $\mathcal{F}_x$ now proof that $ \mathcal{F}_x \cup \{1\}$ still commutes with all maps but there are at least two maps from $ \mathcal{F}_x \to \mathcal{F}_x \cup \{1\}$ .

For the 2. question the if direction is easy, for only if assume there is no such open set then all the maps $\mathcal{F}(U)\to \mathcal{F}_x$ are not injective (for $U$ small enough) and you can construct "another" stalk $\mathcal{F}'_x$ which has one element more. Suppose $f,g$ are the elements in question. We know that they get maped to the same element in $\mathcal{F}_x$ under the maps $\varphi_U$ (here I assume that $U\subset V\cap W$ where $V,W$ are the sets where $f,g$ come from). Now define the maps $\varphi'_U :\mathcal{F}(U)\to \mathcal{F}_x\cup \{*\} $ by

$$ \varphi'_U(x)= \begin{cases}  * \qquad \text{ if } x \in res_{U',U}^{-1}(g_{\vert U'}) \text{ for some } U'\subset U\\
\varphi_U(x)\qquad \text{else } \\\end{cases}. $$

Now a map $\alpha: \mathcal{F}_x\to \mathcal{F}_x\cup \{*\}$ with the property $\alpha\circ \varphi_U=\varphi'_U$ cant exist because $f,g$ get send to the same element by $\varphi_U$ and therefore by $\alpha\circ \varphi_U$ but to different elements by $\varphi_U'$.

Comment: In your first paragraph, the notations make it unclear whether you are suggesting we remove $f$ from $\mathcal F_x$ or add an extra element $1$. At any rate, I agree that in the category of sets, that part is easy since we can take the identity map $\mathcal F_x \to \mathcal F_x$, grab any element that is not reached from below and send it anywhere we want: this provides multiple cocone endomorphisms.

Comment: @Cotton I added a element to avoid the case where the stalk only has one element. But I agree, you can avoid this case with other arguments.

Comment: I entirely don't follow the second part: is it surprising that $\mathcal F(U) \to \mathcal F_x$ is not injective? And, if you just add an element ($\mathcal F_x' = \mathcal F_x \sqcup \{*\})$, wouldn't the inclusion $\mathcal F_x \to \mathcal F'_x$ make everything commute?

Comment: @Cotton  Ok, I expand my argument for the second part. Give me a second.

Comment: @Cotton Edited.

Comment: What are $\varphi'_W, \varphi'_V$? They cannot be $\varphi_W, \varphi_V$ since $g \mapsto g \in \mathcal F(U) \mapsto * \in \mathcal F_x$ contradicts $\varphi_W(g) = \varphi_V(f)$ which is equal to $\varphi_U$ of the restriction of $f$ to $U$.

Comment: @Cotton This is why I said you need to adjust all the maps accordingly. OK, let my give you a hint: you have the restriction map $res_{U,V}:\mathcal{F}(V)\to \mathcal{F}(U)$ now define $\varphi_V'$ by sending $res_{U,V}^{-1}(g)$ to $\{*\}$. Note that you need to adjust all the maps in this way s.t. the respective diagramms stay commutative.

Comment: I misread $U \subset U'$ as $U' \subset U$. Let me think about it.

Comment: @Cotton There are actually some more problems with this argument. Let me think about it.

Comment: @Cotton Edited the map again, I hope it's fine now.

Comment: Take an open set $A$, a function $h \in \mathcal F(A)$. Assume there exists $C$ such that $h_{|C} = g_{|C}$ (so, $C$ must be in $A \cap W$). By definition, your $\varphi'_A$ sends $h$ to $*$. Now take a smaller $B \subset A$. For the relevant triangle to commute, necessarily, you must be able to find $C' \subset B \cap W$ with $h_{|C'} = g_{|C'}$ (because $h_{|B}$ gets sent to $*$). What if $B$ is a subset of $A$ that happens to be disjoint from $W$?

Comment: @Cotton This can't happen since all relevant open sets contain $x$.

Comment: I believe I have run out of objections (for now!). Do you have any reference for sheaves of rings or (I should hope) arbitrary filtered colimits?

Comment: @Cotton :) Unfortunately not. But you can do literally the same arguments by replacing $\mathcal{F}_x$ with $\mathcal{F}_x[y]$ the polynomial ring with variable $y$.

Comment: I thought about that but how do you define the $\varphi'_U$ so that they are ring homomorphisms?

Comment: You are right, you might need $\mathcal{F}_x[y,y^{-1}]$. But I have to think about it tomorrow, need to go sleep now.